# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; White spaces are required between publicId and systemId

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, sax

I am writing  a Java desktop application in Eclipse Oxygen with JavaFX. I am trying to read a url that contains an XML document but I am getting the error;

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
```

The script looks like this;

```
private static Document loadTestDocument(String url) {
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        Document k = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new URL(url).openStream());
        return k;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setHeaderText("Could not load data");
        alert.setContentText("Could not load data from file:\n" + e.getMessage());

        alert.showAndWait();
        return null;
    }
}
```

The XML document is very basic and it looks like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><STOREITEMS><PRODUCT ITEM='R7876' NAME='REMOVED'>


<STOCK>In Stock</STOCK></PRODUCT>
<PRODUCT ITEM='BR122293' NAME='REMOVED'>


<STOCK>In Stock</STOCK></PRODUCT>
<PRODUCT ITEM='REMOVED' NAME='REMOVED'>


<STOCK>In Stock</STOCK></PRODUCT>
<PRODUCT ITEM='ASTRO' NAME='REMOVED'>


<STOCK>In Stock</STOCK></PRODUCT>
<PRODUCT ITEM='3002028110' NAME='REMOVED'>


<STOCK>In Stock</STOCK></PRODUCT>
<PRODUCT ITEM='0340' NAME='REMOVED'>


<STOCK>No Stock.</STOCK></PRODUCT>
<PRODUCT ITEM='570031' NAME='REMOVED'> ...
```

I will then use Unmarshaller or JAXB to convert it into a document like this;

```
private static StoreItems loadStoreItemsFromXMLDocument(Document doc) {
    try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
                .newInstance(StoreItems.class);
        Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
        // Reading XML from the file and unmarshalling.
        StoreItems storeItems = (StoreItems) um.unmarshal(doc);
        ...
        return storeItems;

    } catch (Exception e) { // catches ANY exception
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

This was working fine. Then when I continued working on the project today, I started getting the error. The document changes.

**Update:**
This is what I get in HexView using fiddler;

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 26 Oct 2017 00:35:35 GMT
Server: nginx
Last-Modified: Wed, 25 Oct 2017 23:01:06 GMT
ETag: "8dbd7-55c6707d75e08"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 580567
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
Expires: Sat, 25 Nov 2017 00:35:35 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=1, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/xml

ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><STOREITEMS><PRODUCT ITEM='R7876' NAME='Rimba Electro Stimulation Gloves Pair'>...
```

This I believe is the Hex form of the HexView above;

```
byte[] arrOutput = { 0x48, 0x54, 0x54, 0x50, 0x2F, 0x31, 0x2E, 0x31, 0x20, 0x32, 0x30, 0x30, 0x20, 0x4F, 0x4B, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x44, 0x61, 0x74, 0x65, 0x3A, 0x20, 0x54, 0x68, 0x75, 0x2C, 0x20, 0x32, 0x36, 0x20, 0x4F, 0x63, 0x74, 0x20, 0x32, 0x30, 0x31, 0x37, 0x20, 0x30, 0x30, 0x3A, 0x33, 0x35, 0x3A, 0x33, 0x35, 0x20, 0x47, 0x4D, 0x54, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x53, 0x65, 0x72, 0x76, 0x65, 0x72, 0x3A, 0x20, 0x6E, 0x67, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x78, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x4C, 0x61, 0x73, 0x74, 0x2D, 0x4D, 0x6F, 0x64, 0x69, 0x66, 0x69, 0x65, 0x64, 0x3A, 0x20, 0x57, 0x65, 0x64, 0x2C, 0x20, 0x32, 0x35, 0x20, 0x4F, 0x63, 0x74, 0x20, 0x32, 0x30, 0x31, 0x37, 0x20, 0x32, 0x33, 0x3A, 0x30, 0x31, 0x3A, 0x30, 0x36, 0x20, 0x47, 0x4D, 0x54, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x45, 0x54, 0x61, 0x67, 0x3A, 0x20, 0x22, 0x38, 0x64, 0x62, 0x64, 0x37, 0x2D, 0x35, 0x35, 0x63, 0x36, 0x37, 0x30, 0x37, 0x64, 0x37, 0x35, 0x65, 0x30, 0x38, 0x22, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x41, 0x63, 0x63, 0x65, 0x70, 0x74, 0x2D, 0x52, 0x61, 0x6E, 0x67, 0x65, 0x73, 0x3A, 0x20, 0x62, 0x79, 0x74, 0x65, 0x73, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x43, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x74, 0x65, 0x6E, 0x74, 0x2D, 0x4C, 0x65, 0x6E, 0x67, 0x74, 0x68, 0x3A, 0x20, 0x35, 0x38, 0x30, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x43, 0x61, 0x63, 0x68, 0x65, 0x2D, 0x43, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x74, 0x72, 0x6F, 0x6C, 0x3A, 0x20, 0x6D, 0x61, 0x78, 0x2D, 0x61, 0x67, 0x65, 0x3D, 0x32, 0x35, 0x39, 0x32, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x45, 0x78, 0x70, 0x69, 0x72, 0x65, 0x73, 0x3A, 0x20, 0x53, 0x61, 0x74, 0x2C, 0x20, 0x32, 0x35, 0x20, 0x4E, 0x6F, 0x76, 0x20, 0x32, 0x30, 0x31, 0x37, 0x20, 0x30, 0x30, 0x3A, 0x33, 0x35, 0x3A, 0x33, 0x35, 0x20, 0x47, 0x4D, 0x54, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x4B, 0x65, 0x65, 0x70, 0x2D, 0x41, 0x6C, 0x69, 0x76, 0x65, 0x3A, 0x20, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6D, 0x65, 0x6F, 0x75, 0x74, 0x3D, 0x31, 0x2C, 0x20, 0x6D, 0x61, 0x78, 0x3D, 0x31, 0x30, 0x30, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x43, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x6E, 0x65, 0x63, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x3A, 0x20, 0x4B, 0x65, 0x65, 0x70, 0x2D, 0x41, 0x6C, 0x69, 0x76, 0x65, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x43, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x74, 0x65, 0x6E, 0x74, 0x2D, 0x54, 0x79, 0x70, 0x65, 0x3A, 0x20, 0x61, 0x70, 0x70, 0x6C, 0x69, 0x63, 0x61, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x2F, 0x78, 0x6D, 0x6C, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF, 0x3C, 0x3F, 0x78, 0x6D, 0x6C, 0x20, 0x76, 0x65, 0x72, 0x73, 0x69, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x3D, 0x22, 0x31, 0x2E, 0x30, 0x22, 0x20, 0x65, 0x6E, 0x63, 0x6F, 0x64, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x67, 0x3D, 0x22, 0x55, 0x54, 0x46, 0x2D, 0x38, 0x22, 0x3F, 0x3E, 0x3C, 0x53, 0x54, 0x4F, 0x52, 0x45, 0x49, 0x54, 0x45, 0x4D, 0x53, 0x3E, 0x3C, 0x50, 0x52, 0x4F, 0x44, 0x55, 0x43, 0x54, 0x20, 0x49, 0x54, 0x45, 0x4D, 0x3D, 0x27, 0x52, 0x37, 0x38, 0x37, 0x36, 0x27, 0x20, 0x4E, 0x41, 0x4D, 0x45, 0x3D, 0x27, 0x52, 0x69, 0x6D, 0x62, 0x61, 0x20, 0x45, 0x6C, 0x65, 0x63, 0x74, 0x72, 0x6F, 0x20, 0x53, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6D, 0x75, 0x6C, 0x61, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x20, 0x47, 0x6C, 0x6F, 0x76, 0x65, 0x73, 0x20, 0x50, 0x61, 0x69, 0x72, 0x27, 0x3E, 0x0A, 0x0A, 0x0A, 0x3C, 0x53, 0x54, 0x4F, 0x43, 0x4B, 0x3E, 0x49, 0x6E, 0x20, 0x53, 0x74, 0x6F, 0x63, 0x6B, 0x3C, 0x2F, 0x53, 0x54, 0x4F, 0x43, 0x4B, 0x3E, 0x3C, 0x2F, 0x50, 0x52, 0x4F, 0x44, 0x55, 0x43, 0x54, 0x3E, 0x0A };
```

Comment: The XML document "looks" like ... maybe there is extra data being sent before the XML header.  You need to examine the data being returned from the URL byte by byte (in hex) to verify it really "looks" like what you posted.  Even extra whitespace prior to the opening `<?xml` could cause a problem.

Comment: I have added what I get in HexView. I see this; `ï»¿` Could that be a problem?

Comment: Yes. I believe that looks like a UTF-8 BOM (Byte Order Mark), which you would have to remove before processing.  Can you post the raw byte values in hex to confirm it's a BOM?

Comment: Fiddler could not allow me to copy the exact characters in the rectangle. That is what I could get. It appears to be adding 2 characters before each entry. It looks like BOM after doing some research. The problem now is how to avoid the error using my script.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is a Unicode "zero-width-space" character, code point `0xFEFF`, which when it appears at the beginning of a file is a Byte-Order-Mark which helps the receiver determine if the stream is big-endian or little-endian.

The server has encoded this in UTF-8 resulting in the string `0xEFBBBF`, which fiddler has "helpfully" (and incorrectly) interpreted as if it were ISO-8859-1.

If you control the server, have it not send the BOM in the first place.  Also, the HTTP response does not specify UTF-8, which it should.

Comment: I have no control of the server. Is there a way to change my code to accept BOM?

Comment: You'll have to find a way to explicitly specify the input encoding.  `DocumentBuilder` can read an `InputSource`, which can be built from an `InputStream` and then have an encoding set with `setEncoding()`.  It's been a while since I looked at this so you may have to play around with it.